# How to know the number of elements of an array while accessing through a pointer to that array

Tags: c, arrays, loops, pointers, struct

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
int n;
char l;
} dat;

void printa(dat* x){
while(*x != NULL){
printf("%c %d\n",x->l,x->n);
x++;
}
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
dat new[10]={
{4,'d'},
{7,'g'},
{3,'c'},
{6,'f'},
{2,'b'},
{5,'e'},
{1,'a'}
};
dat* x=new;
printa(x);
return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to display values through a pre-populated struct so that later I can make a sorting function on them.

The line containing `while(*x != NULL)` is problematic to the compiler. It states `error: invalid operands to binary !=`. I then changed it to `while(*x)` thinking that I got messed up with declaration of pointers, and the compiler complains with `error: used struct type value where scalar is required`. I then proceeded to change the line to `while(x)`. The compiler did not complain yet, executing the code produced random values along with a segmentation fault.

I then proceeded to run the faulty compiled code through gdb and it states

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x0804838f in printa ()

I could easily fix my issue by modifying my code to match something like this:

```
void printa(dat* x){
int num=0;
while(num++ < 2){
printf("%c %d\n",x->l,x->n);
x++;
}
}
```

But I'd rather have the struct array go through completely (printing all elements) instead of stopping at a fixed number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pointer will never be NULL if it starts with a valid address and then gets incremented.

You need to modify your data so the loop knows when to stop.

1. Use `while (x->n != 0)`.
2. Add `{0, 0}` at the end of your data initializer.

If zero is a valid value in your data then you'll need to adjust that, of course.

Comment: You need to add the `{0,0}` also, or else you're just relying on there being zeroed memory off the end of your table. This is not unlikely but in no way guaranteed. IOW, you're leaning on "Undefined Behaviour".

Answer (score 2):

No, what you want cannot be achieve *directly*. Once you use a *pointer* to point to an *array*, the pointer does not inherit any information abut the array size. So, you cannot pass the pointer to a function and expect to calcuate the *valid* length of the array through that pointer.

You have to follow either of the below methods

1. Pass the length of the array as a second parameter to the function.
2. Use a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) in the array and check for the value in the function to stop accessing.